# Unable to access dynamic property

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq

I have a `dynamic` object and I am unable to access its properties.

I modified the code below for readability.

I'm using package : `Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll`

I am trying to read the object `mDevice` in the code below:

**Code**

```
foreach (dynamic mDevice in dynamicList.mobile_devices)
{
    MobileDevice mobileDevice = new MobileDevice() //====> Throws Exception
    {
        Id = mDevice.id,
        Name = mDevice.name
    };
}
```

The `Exception` is as following:

> 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'id'

If I use my `Watch Window` to output the `mDevice` before the `Exception` occurs, I get the following result:

[image: Watch Window]

Can anyone explain me why I cannot access the properties?

**Update**
`dynamicList` Origin:

**IGNORE** the reason why I am converting XML into JSON this has other irrelevant purposes

```
string MobileDevicesInJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
dynamic dynamicList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MobileDevicesInJSON);
```

**Original JSON:**

```
{"?xml":{"@version":"1.0","@encoding":"UTF-8"},"mobile_device_application":{"general":{"id":"5","name":"Acta Dome Calculator - Free","display_name":"Acta Dome Calculator - Free","description":null,"bundle_id":"com.itwcalculator.calculatorforipadfree","version":"3.1.1","internal_app":"true","category":{"id":"-1","name":"No category assigned"},"ipa":{"name":null,"uri":null,"data":null},"icon":null,"mobile_device_provisioning_profile":null,"url":{"@deprecated":"9.4","#text":"https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/calculator-free/id398129933?mt=8&uo=4"},"itunes_store_url":"https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/calculator-free/id398129933?mt=8&uo=4","deployment_type":"Install Automatically/Prompt Users to Install","deploy_automatically":"true","deploy_as_managed_app":"true","remove_app_when_mdm_profile_is_removed":"false","prevent_backup_of_app_data":"false","keep_description_and_icon_up_to_date":"false","free":"true","take_over_management":"false","host_externally":"true","external_url":"https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/calculator-free/id398129933?mt=8&uo=4","site":{"id":"1","name":"Acta Dome"}},"scope":{"all_mobile_devices":"false","all_jss_users":"false","mobile_devices":{"mobile_device":{"id":"9","name":"iPad R&D 01S","udid":"dd1dff5d598e3fce0b4b16288f0b9bf1551d0eb2","wifi_mac_address":"9C:35:EB:53:00:84"}},"mobile_device_groups":{"mobile_device_group":{"id":"9","name":"Acta Dome Unassigned"}},"buildings":null,"departments":null,"jss_users":{"user":[{"id":"9","name":"ACTA_Astrid"},{"id":"7","name":"ACTA_RenD01"}]},"jss_user_groups":{"user_group":{"id":"7","name":"Acta Dome StudentGroup 01"}},"limit_to_users":{"user_groups":null},"network_limitations":{"any_ip_address":"true","network_segments":null},"limitations":{"users":null,"user_groups":null,"network_segments":null},"exclusions":{"mobile_devices":null,"mobile_device_groups":null,"buildings":null,"departments":null,"jss_users":null,"jss_user_groups":null,"users":null,"user_groups":null,"network_segments":null}},"self_service":{"self_service_description":null,"self_service_icon":null,"feature_on_main_page":"false","self_service_categories":null}}}
```

Comment: What is the actual type of `mDevice` inside of the loop, is it `JProperty`?

Comment: Yes, hat is what my immediate window tells me but that feels wrong... Shouldn't it be JPropertyList?

Comment: Maybe you should access `mDevice.mobile_device.id`?

Comment: Same: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'mobile_device'

Comment: What is the type of `dynamicList` and how did you get it? What is the original JSON?

Comment: Updated code, but does it really matter? I'm wondering why I cannot acces the properties in 'mDevice' wich is already populated

Comment: Expand the `mDevice` variable in the Locals or Watch window and see what is in there. Immediate window is not good for showing the structure.

Comment: Replace the Immediate with Watch window. See updated post

Comment: @NickProzee: Give us some JSON to recreate the issue. Almost certainly the problem is that the deserialization hasn't done what you expected but without a testable reproducible version of the error its hard to say for sure where your problem is. I've attempted to reproduce your problem myself and it works fine for me so its kind of hard to help...

Comment: Try mDevice["id"] instead and also check case, possibly you have Id or ID property

Comment: As an example looking at your watch window I notice that the top level item's string representation starts `{"mobile_device": ...` which suggests to me that maybe you are after `mDevice.mobile_device` or something first. Its kinda guesswork though...

Comment: I added original JSON for those who need it

Comment: Thanks for the JSON. It confuses me slightly though. Looking for mobile_devices in there I can only see it under mobile_device_application/scope but it doesn't seem to be an array so I am not sure why you are foreaching over it. The JSON you gave certainly doesn't seem to be that you are using in your answer (ie if MobileDevicesInJSON was what you gave then I wouldn't expect `dynamicList.mobile_devices` to come back with anything) so I'm not sure if that is just because you are doing somethign else first?. Did you try doing `mDevice.mobile_device.id` out of interest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the Type column in the Watch window (that you haven't fully shown in your post, and it contains a quite important information), you will see that the type of the `mDevice` is `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty` (which btw is also implied from the exception message) and not a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` as you expect. Which in turn means the `dynamicList.mobile_devices` is not a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray` as you expect, and indeed it is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` instance. So the whole logic is wrong. Here is a working example based on the "Original JSON" from the post:

```
string originalJSON = ...;
dynamic root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(originalJSON);
dynamic mobileDevices = root.mobile_device_application.scope.mobile_devices;
dynamic mobileDevice = mobileDevices.mobile_device;
var id = (int)mobileDevice.id;
var name = (string)mobileDevice.name;
```

or alternatively

```
foreach (var item in mobileDevices)
{
    dynamic mobileDevice = item.Value;
    var id = (int)mobileDevice.id;
    var name = (string)mobileDevice.name;
}
```

As a general advice, start using the Locals/Watch window capabilities other than values. For instance, there is something called "Dynamic View" which appears at the bottom of the expanded object with dynamic support, which in this case shows :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the brief and clear answer, this explains what is going wrong!

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic object here is a dictionary(key value pair) where "**mobile_device**" is a key and corresponding object containing  *id,name* etc is value of this key.

you should be able to  access that using **mobile_device** as key on mDevice   like mDevice["**mobile_device**"]. This should return you an object which again has key value pairs (*id* key and *9* is value , *name* key and *ipad* is value ....). again use the same syntax (key/value) on the object returned to get the corresponding value.

Comment: Trying to acces its like mDevice["mobile_device"] or mDevice["mobile_device"].Key throws an Exception: Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the object, change to this code it should work:

```
    Id = mDevice.mobile_device.id,
    Name = mDevice.mobile_device.name
```

this is clear from your watch window.

---

I don't see anything called `mobile_devices`  -- do you mean `mobile_device`?

The code you show should not iterate the loop because that property name shouldn't exist.

Comment: Yes, because dynamicList.mobile_devices is a list of 'mobile_device'. I left that one out in the code above because it is not relevant, I'm scoping to 'mDevice'

Answer (score 0):

This could be a solution.

```
foreach (dynamic mDevice in dynamicList)
{
    object mDeviceProperties = mDevice.Value;

    var mobileDevice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileDevice>(mDeviceProperties.ToString());
}
```

Comment: The question is: Can anyone explain me why I cannot access the properties?. Please take a look at @Ivan Stoev how an informative answer should look like....

Comment: You just deserialize mDevice to object that's why you can't access the properies. mDevice has to be deserialized to MobileDevice then the properties can be accessed. Hope this is answering your question at least in parts.